# Faceted search on multilist in sitecore 7

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I'm able to generate the facet and bind the result in `Linkbutton` within repeater control. Now I'm facing problem in generating the facet query with `OR` operator when the user selects more than 1 value of same facet type in Sitecore 7.

What can be done to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the OR operator? Normally in a faceted search, when a user selects multiple facets they are ADDED. So if I filter stackoverflow by C# and Sitecore it will return me results that only match BOTH of those, not EITHER.  Can you post an example of how you have tried it so far?

Comment: OR is a pretty normal operator.  If the facet is template type maybe I want to see Press Releases and Publications (logical or) for my search term.  Or in shopping... Brown or Red shoes...

Comment: I need to add OR operator on selecting multiple value in the same facet and "And" operator between the 2 different facet. So I need help in implementing the same using SITECORE 7

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same using LINQ but no success as I don't have expertise on LINQ. I think I need to prepare the Expression and append the same to my base query.

Answer (score 1):

To implement the Facet search in Sitecore use PredicateBuilder class to build the filter query and then add the filter query to the base query. Code is mentioned below:

```
        List<PeopleFields> objPeoplefields = new List<PeopleFields>();
        IQueryable<PeopleFields> Query = null;
        var predicatePractice = Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.PredicateBuilder.False<PeopleFields>();
        var predicateOffice = Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.PredicateBuilder.False<PeopleFields>();

        using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(SITECORE_WEB_INDEX).CreateSearchContext())
        {
            //Base query
            Query = context.GetQueryable<PeopleFields>().Where(i => i.FirstName.StartsWith(txtFirstName.Text)).Where(i => i.LastName.StartsWith(txtLastName.Text));
            foreach (string strselecteFacet in lstPracticefacetSelected)
            {
                //filter query
                predicatePractice = predicatePractice.Or(x => x.Practice.Like(strselecteFacet));
            }

            foreach (string strselecteFacet in lstOfficefacetSelected)
            {
                //Filter query
                predicateOffice = predicateOffice.Or(x => x.Office.Like(strselecteFacet));
            }

            //Joining the filter query alongwith base query
            if (lstPracticefacetSelected.Count > 0 && lstOfficefacetSelected.Count > 0)
                Query = Query.Filter(predicatePractice).Filter(predicateOffice);
            else if (lstPracticefacetSelected.Count > 0 && lstOfficefacetSelected.Count == 0)
                Query = Query.Filter(predicatePractice);
            else if (lstPracticefacetSelected.Count == 0 && lstOfficefacetSelected.Count > 0)
                Query = Query.Filter(predicateOffice);

            objPeoplefields = Query.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post about solving this using PredicateBuilder with a specific code example:

http://www.nttdatasitecore.com/en/Blog/2013/November/Building-Facet-Queries-with-PredicateBuilder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As a quick way, if you're ok with having `SitecoreUISearchResultItem` as the query result type, you may be able to utilize the same method Sitecore 7 uses to parse queries entered in the content editor search:

```
Sitecore.Buckets.Util.UIFilterHelpers.ParseDatasourceString(string query)
```

If that's not up to what you're after, reading how it's implemented with a decompiler (ILSpy, DotPeek, Reflector, Resharper, etc) may help you in composing an expression manually based on dynamic criteria.